# networking port forwarding to ssh tunnel

Tags: iptables, ssh-tunnel, forwarding

I have a quick question regarding Linux port forwarding to an ssh tunnel.
A ssh (reverse) tunnel connected to a web service on one machine is terminated on one machine, such that the service is available on localhost:40001 on the terminating host. This works !

If I connect from an application on the terminating machine to localhost:40001 I can access the web service. But now I want to move the application from that local machine to another machine, whilst keeping the tunnel to the terminator.

I now have to either use a (web) proxy on the terminator, or forward all traffic to (and from)the application through the tunnel terminating machine to localhost:40001 on that box.

So what firewall (iptables) rules should I apply here to get this rolling ?

thanks !
Rudi

Answer (score 0):

This has nothing to do with iptables unless you already have iptables enabled in restricted mode (default `DROP`). If so, you just need to allow the needed ports through your server/firewall.